# Android ViewPager taking FrameLayouts Touch

Tags: android, android-layout

In the below Framelayout half of vertical portion is an image viewpager and other half is some texts and buttons. When I click on the viewpager image the bottom half will hide to see the image as full screen. The whole layout is vertical swipable, when i swipe vertically new data comes. Because of the viewpager vertical swipe is not working(It was alright when I put imageview instead of viewpager). when I swipe vertically viewpagers touch is triggered. Is there any way to disable the touch of viewpager for the bottom half of the layout or when I swipe vertically the layout default touch should be triggered and when horizontally the viewpagers touch.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ViewPager android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center" />
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" app:layout_heightPercent="50%" android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" app:layout_heightPercent="50%" android:orientation="vertical" tools:ignore="UselessParent">
            <TextView />
            <TextView />
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="10" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp">
                <TextView />
                <TextView />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="10" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp">
                <TextView />
                <Button android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Share" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

[image: The Parent PercentFrameLayout touch will trigger vertical swiping which now is not working because of viewpager]